# protect app from hook using frida objection

Tags: java, android, frida

How to protect android applications from Dynamic Instrumentation/Runtime hooking using objection from Frida

```
objection --gadget "package,name" explore
```

Agent injected and responded ok! This message came even though the application threw a message saying "root detected"

How to programmatically protect the app from this

Comment: There is a general problem asking for counter-measures against reversing tools in public. What ever we answer you, most likely the counter-counter-measure will be implemented in objection a little time later. really good protections have the problem that they may be limited to certain Android versions. Also the changed made by Android manufacturer makes it pretty complicated, so developing a hooking protection requires you to have a really large set of physical test devices to make sure the protection does not back-fire on certain devices.